# PrimeNG textarea not working size with formControlName

Tags: angular, forms, primeng

I am trying to connect textarea using formControlName. But crashes, any size settings and the form begins to uncontrollably expand in width. Until the bottom scroll appears, breaking everything in its path.
I have tried a bunch of css options and settings. The only solution I have found is to set via [(ngModel)] and setValue to a form. But it looks like bad code and not best practice.
But if there is no [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" tag, I get an error.
And as soon as I set the [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" parameter, then all the width-wise input behavior in the layout immediately breaks again.
how to be?

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UntypedFormControl, UntypedFormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-shared-form-el-descriptions-smoll',
    templateUrl: './form-el-descriptions-smoll.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form-el-descriptions-smoll.component.scss'],

})
export class FormElDescriptionsSmollComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() form!: UntypedFormGroup;
    @Input() label: string;
    @Input() RUCtrl!: UntypedFormControl;
    @Input() UACtrl!: UntypedFormControl;
    @Input() controlName: string;

    public text = '';

    constructor() {
        this.controlName = '';
        this.label = '';
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }


    public setTextareaValue(): void {
        // @ts-ignore
        this.form.get('smallDescriptionUA').setValue(this.text);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
        <div class="field col-6">
            <!-- 1 Not working [autoResize]="false"-->
            <textarea
                [autoResize]="false"
                [formControlName]="'smallDescriptionUA'"
                cols="30"
                pInputTextarea
                rows="4">
            </textarea>
            <!-- 2 Not working [autoResize]="true"-->
            <textarea
                [autoResize]="true"
                [formControlName]="'smallDescriptionUA'"
                cols="30"
                pInputTextarea
                rows="4">
            </textarea>
            <!-- 3 Not working [autoResize]="false" style="resize: none;"-->
            <textarea
                [autoResize]="false"
                [formControlName]="'smallDescriptionUA'"
                cols="30"
                pInputTextarea
                rows="4"
                style="resize: none;">
            </textarea>
            <!-- 4 Not working [autoResize]="true" style="resize: none;"-->
            <textarea
                [formControlName]="'smallDescriptionUA'"
                cols="30"
                pInputTextarea
                rows="4"
                style="resize: none;">
            </textarea>

            <!-- 5 working ngModel + [autoResize]="true" -->
            <div class="field">
                <textarea
                    (keyup)="setTextareaValue()"
                    [(ngModel)]="text"
                    [autoResize]="true"
                    cols="30"
                    pInputTextarea
                    rows="4">
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <!-- 6 working ngModel + [autoResize]="false" -->
            <div class="field">
                <textarea
                    (keyup)="setTextareaValue()"
                    [(ngModel)]="text"
                   
                    [autoResize]="false"
                    cols="30"
                    maxlength="250"
                    pInputTextarea
                    rows="4">
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <!-- 7 working ngModel + style="resize: none;" -->
            <div class="field">
                <textarea
                    (keyup)="setTextareaValue()"
                    [(ngModel)]="text"
                    
                    cols="30"
                    maxlength="250"
                    pInputTextarea
                    rows="4">
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <!-- 8 working v2-->
            <textarea
                (keyup)="setTextareaValue()"
                [(ngModel)]="text"
                
                cols="30"
                maxlength="250"
                pInputTextarea
                rows="4"
                style="resize: none;">
            </textarea>

            <!-- 9 working v3-->
            <div class="field ">
                <div class="p-float-label">
                   <textarea (keyup)="setTextareaValue()"
                             [(ngModel)]="text"
                             
                             cols="60"
                             id="textarea"
                             maxlength="250"
                             pInputTextarea
                             rows="5"
                             style="resize: none;">

                   </textarea>
                    <label for="textarea">Textarea</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p-message
                *ngIf="RUCtrl?.errors && (RUCtrl.dirty || RUCtrl.touched)"
                severity="error" text="Поле обязательно!"></p-message>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

[image: Error if there is no tag [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"]

Answer (score 0):

It's working with `formControl` instead of `formControlName`

for example

```js
get formControl() {
  return this.form.controls[`${this.controlName}`] as FormControl
}
```

```
  <textarea
    pInputTextarea
    [formControl]="formControl"
    [autoResize]="false"
    cols="30"
    rows="4"
  >
  </textarea>
```